# Adding children to a parental census event in MacFamilyTree 10

Tags: macfamilytree

I am just beginning to get to grips with MacFamilyTree and I can see how I can create a Family Event Type for a census entry and that this links together the husband and wife. What I cannot work out is how I can link the children who appear on this census entry with the same event. Is this possible and if so how?